# How can I make my bot send me a private message when a user gets a specific role?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a quiz, when a person answers the last question, they get a 'Completed' role. When they get the role, I want my bot to send me a private message. Is it possible to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_member_update` event will fire whenever a role is added. We can check that the role is not in the roles of the member before the event and is present after the update:

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role_name = "Completed"
    if not get(before.roles, name=role_name) and get(after.roles, name=role_name):
        await bot.owner.send(f"{after.name} has finished")
```